# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, typeerror

Working with Ajax... I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong here. The error occurs on the code: **objUserID.innerHTML = username;**. It thinks the variable **username** is null. **username** does have data in it because the following code confirms it: **console.log("user: ["+username+"]");** Can anyone figure this out?

```
function actionBid(bidID,bidA,bidAction){
   var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
   {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
   { 
      // ==== GET BID ====
      if (bidAction == "getbid"){

      var objUserID = document.getElementById("curBidUser"+bidID); 
      var res = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
      var username = res.substring(0,res.indexOf(','));
      console.log("user: ["+username+"]");
      objUserID.innerHTML = username;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about what your problem is?

Comment: may be there is no , in response

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Comment: Why are you accessing `XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText` before you send the AJAX request?

Comment: Do you even make an Ajax request??? Seems like you are missing a lot of code.

Comment: Honestly, the Ajax call doesn't matter at this point.  As Niet points out in his answer, the problem is tat the code can't find an element with an `id` value of `"curBidUser"+bidID`.  We need to see the HTML code and know what `bidID` is equal to, to figure out why.

Comment: The Ajax is working correctly - I did not include all the code because it is a bit lengthy. However, it was solved below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It thinks the variable **username** is null

False. It is telling you that it cannot access the property `innerHTML` of `null`. In other words, that `objUserID` is null and that you cannot access a property of it.

Put another way, your element does not exist.

Comment: You are correct, the element was missing. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

If you are having this problem, it might be because you have placed your script tag at the top of the body tag before everything else. You want to place your script tag at the bottom of the body tag.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was an loading issue check with the follow code.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  xYzFunction();    
}, 3000 )
```

Comment: this is not a valid solution, user won't wait for 3 seconds!!!

Answer (score 0):

It means that the element or the object is not found. It doesn't exist.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/cF6Bh/

You can see, that the code works. But the element's not present for the JavaScript to work on.

Make sure that the element is present. Either you need to make sure the characters are OK or something like that.

```
document.getElementById("objectId").innerHTML = "Text";
```

So the remedy to this would be, to change the ID param that you're passing onto the method.

Comment: You are correct. The element was missing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

actually this error can be also caused by calling like this `document.getElementById("#content-content").innerHTML=output;`

instead of like this

```
document.getElementById("content-content").innerHTML=output;
```